# Indications and corrections appear immediately after the exercise statement

Tags: numbering, exercises, answers

In order to use the answer package, I downloaded a file that contains this package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{answers}

\setlength{\paperwidth}{21cm}
\setlength{\paperheight}{29.7cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-2.5cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.7cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{1cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{25cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{17cm}

\newtheorem{Exc}{Exercice}
\Newassociation{correction}{Soln}{mycor}
\Newassociation{indication}{Indi}{myind}
\renewcommand{\Solnlabel}[1]{\bf \emph{Correction #1}}
\renewcommand{\Indilabel}[1]{\bf \emph{Indication #1}}

\def\exo#1{\futurelet\testchar\MaybeOptArgmyexoo}
\def\MaybeOptArgmyexoo{\ifx[\testchar \let\next\OptArgmyexoo
                        \else \let\next\NoOptArgmyexoo \fi \next}
\def\OptArgmyexoo[#1]{\begin{Exc}[#1]\normalfont}
\def\NoOptArgmyexoo{\begin{Exc}\normalfont}

\newcommand{\finexo}{\end{Exc}}
\newcommand{\flag}[1]{}

\newtheorem{question}{Question}




\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\newcommand{\entete}[1]
{
{\noindent
  \textsf{Biblioth\`eque d'exercices}             
  \hfill \textbf{\textsf{#1}} \\                  
}{\noindent
   \textsf{Topologie}                                     
      \hfill \textsf{Feuille n$^{\circ}\,$2}\\       
}
\hrule
\begin{center}
\textbf{\textsf{\Large
     Continuit\'e                                 
     }}
\end{center}
\hrule
\vspace*{1cm}
}


\begin{document}


 \Opensolutionfile{mycor}[ficcorex]
 \Opensolutionfile{myind}[ficind]
 \entete{\'Enoncés}

\section*{Applications continues}

\exo{ 0 , queffelec, 01/10/2003, 3, {}}
Soit $X$ un espace topologique et $f:X\to \mathbb R$.
\begin{enumerate}
\item Montrer que $f$ est continue si et seulement si pour tout $\lambda\in \mathbb R$,
les ensembles $\{x\ ;\ f(x)<\lambda\}$ et $\{x\ ;\ f(x)>\lambda\}$ sont des
ouverts de $X$.

\item Montrer que si $f$ est continue, pour tout $\omega$ ouvert de $\mathbb R$,
$f^{-1}(\omega)$ est un $F_\sigma$ ouvert de $X$ ($F_\sigma$= r\'eunion
d\'enombrable de ferm\'es).

\end{enumerate}

\begin{indication}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Utiliser le fait que tout ouvert de $\mathbb R$ est l'union dénombrable d'intervalles ouverts.
  \item \'Ecrire un intervalle fermé comme union dénombrable d'intervalles
ouverts, puis utiliser la même remarque que ci-dessus.
   \end{enumerate}
\end{indication}

\begin{correction}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Sens direct. Si $f$ est continue alors $\{x \mid f(x) < \lambda\} =
f^{-1}(]-\infty,\lambda[)$ est un ouvert comme image réciproque par une application continue de l'intervalle ouvert $]-\infty,\lambda[$. De même avec
$]\lambda,+\infty[$.

Réciproque. Tout d'abord, tout intervalle ouvert $]a,b[$, ($a<b$) peut s'écrire
$$]a,b[= ]-\infty,b[ \cap ]a,+\infty[.$$
Donc
$$f^{-1}(]a,b[) = f^{-1}(]-\infty,b[) \cap f^{-1}(]a,+\infty[)$$
est une intersection de deux ouverts donc un ouvert de $X$.
Soit $O$ un ouvert de $\mathbb R$, alors $O$ peut s'écrire comme l'union dénombrables d'intervalles ouverts :
$$O = \bigcup_{i\in I} {]a_i,b_i[}.$$
Donc
$$f^{-1}(O)= \bigcup_{i\in I} f^{-1}(]a_i,b_i[)$$
est une union d'ouvert donc un ouvert de $X$ .
  \item Nous le faisons d'abord pour un intervalle ouvert $]a,b[$.
$$]a,b[ = \bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{N}^*} [a+\frac 1n,b-\frac 1n].$$
Donc
$$f^{-1}(]a,b[) = \bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{ N} f^{-1}([a+\frac 1j,b-\frac 1j]),$$
est une union dénombrable de fermés.
Maintenant comme pour la première question, tout ouvert $O$ de $\mathbb R$
s'écrit $O = \bigcup_{i\in I} ]a_i,b_i[$, avec $I$ dénombrable.
Donc on peut écrire
$$f^{-1}(O)= \bigcup_{i\in I}\bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{N}^*} f^{-1}([a_i+\frac 1j,b_i-\frac 1j]),$$
qui est une union dénombrable de fermés (mais c'est un ouvert !).
   \end{enumerate}
\end{correction}
\finexo 
\end{document}
```

When compiling, the answers appeared on a new page. The same goes for the indications.
I would like the indications as well as the answers to appear immediately after the statements.

Many thanks for your precious advice.

Comment: The way the questions and answers are organized in my document.

Comment: Once again, Thank you so much. It' s working well. It is an answer to the question.